# JSON AJAX Http request

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I am working with a JSON file that I have, and I am linking it in my JavaScript. 
 I am trying to get it requested through AJAX to show up on my `console.log`, but I am just getting `null` for my `readystatechange` function. What am I doing wrong?

Also to better clarify I am doing this for my course and ideally what my goal is; I have a json file that I created (myjson.com), I have that URL its in my JavaScript, and I am trying to get that json url to update to my JavaScript so when I do a `console.log` it shows up the values of the objects from the json. Here's my code:

```
<div id="btn1"> Update </div>
<div id="output"></div>

<script>

var output = document.getElementById("output");

document.getElementById("btn1").onclick = function () {
    var a = newXMLHttpRequest();
    a.onreadystatechange = function () {

    }
    a.open("GET", "https://api.myjson.com/bins/z79bt", true);
    a.send();
};

</script>
```

---

UPDATE

Code from the comment:

```
var output = document.getElementById("output");
document.getElementById("btn1").onclick = function () { 
  var a = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
  a.onreadystatechange = function () { 
    if(this.readyState == 4) { 
      var myObj = this.responseText; 
    } 
    console.log(a); 
  } 
  a.open("GET", "api.myjson.com/bins/z79bt";, true); 
  a.send(); 
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Two issues:

- you're missing a space in `newXMLHttpRequest`
- you're not doing anything inside the state change callback
- (third: you're also not populating the output div)

See the live example here:

```js
var output = document.getElementById("output");

document.getElementById("btn1").onclick = function () {
    var a = new XMLHttpRequest();
    a.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if(a.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && a.status === 200) {
        console.log(a.responseText);
        output.textContent = a.responseText;
      }
    }
    a.open("GET", "https://api.myjson.com/bins/z79bt", true);
    a.send();
};
```

```html
<div id="btn1"> Update </div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

---

UPDATE

Fixed code from the comment:

```js
var output = document.getElementById("output");
document.getElementById("btn1").onclick = function () { 
  var a = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
  a.onreadystatechange = function () { 
    if(this.readyState == 4) { 
      var myObj = this.responseText; 
      console.log(myObj); 
    } 
    
  } 
  a.open("GET", "https://api.myjson.com/bins/z79bt", true); 
  a.send(); 
};
```

```html
<div id="btn1"> Update </div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks you are right I forgot the space between the new XMLHttpRequest I had one more questions your method with the if statement works and I see that I am getting back my json objects I am following a book step by step and I am still not getting information back when I am doing it this way can you see if anything is wrong?

Comment: var output = document.getElementById("output");

document.getElementById("btn1").onclick = function () {
 var a = new XMLHttpRequest();
 a.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if(this.readyState == 4) {
   var myObj = this.responseText;
  }
   console.log(a);
 }
 a.open("GET", "https://api.myjson.com/bins/z79bt", true);
 a.send();
};

Comment: @user7656142 `myObj` will live only inside the function scope. You're logging the variable `a` instead of `myObj`.